# Multiple 404 pages with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a htaccess that checks the IP and then redirects the user to the appropriate page. Right now I'm using ErrorDocument 404 /404.php but I want to have seperate 404 pages based on the IP. If I place that under the..

```
RewriteCond     %{REMOTE_ADDR} x.x.x.x
```

rule it still goes to the same 404 page. How do I make the 404 page account for the IP like the rest of the pages do?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put conditions before `ErrorDocument` directive.

As a workaround you can use `mod_rewrite` to handle this situation for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handle 404 for IP=x.x.x.x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =x.x.x.x
RewriteRule . /ip1-404.php [L]

# handle 404 for IP=y.y.y.y
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =y.y.y.y
RewriteRule . /ip2-404.php [L]
```